# RXJS How to convert Observable<T[]> to Observable<T>

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I would like to take an Observable<T[]> and convert it to an Observable<T> such that each array from the Observable<T[]> is broken up and the individual elements of the arrays are then emitted, separately, via the Observable<T>.

Is there a standard operator for doing this? I've searched around but haven't found anything. Thanks.

---

After being pointed in the direction of concatMap/flatMap, I came up with the following general solution:

```
var source: Observable<T[]>;
...
var splitSource = source.flatMap<T>((x:T[]) => { return Rx.Observable.fromArray(x); });
```

Comment: No there is no implicit functionality that you describe. You need to write it yourself. This should be fairly easy to do - just iterate over the array.

Comment: Dang! well it shouldn't be hard to implement. Thanks. If you submit that as a response instead of a comment I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: Perhaps someone shows up with a better solution - maybe there is something in the library you can ultimately use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `concatMap` like this:

```
function identity (x) {return x}

var obs_of_array$ = Rx.Observable.return(['1','2','you got it'])
    .concatMap(identity)
```

This works because `concatMap` also accepts arrays (and observables and promises) as the return value of the function selector that you pass as a parameter. Jsbin [here](http://jsfiddle.net/09egztku/3/), documentation [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md)

So the array passed as parameter becomes the return value from the selector function, and then is flattened by the `concatMap` operator while respecting the ordering of the array.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks for the example on jsfiddle. I'll play with it some in TypeScript. I'd prefer something a little more direct, but I can always create a wrapper for this

Comment: After playing with it and flatMap a bit more, I found this worked well for my situation - thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've also been playing around with converting `Observable<T[]>` to `Observable<T>`.

I've found that `flatMap()` does the job on it's own, which I presume was not the case 11 months ago when the question was asked.

To illustrate, in the jsfiddle in @user3743222's answer, you can make this change and get the same output:

```
//.concatMap(identity)
.flatMap(theArray=>theArray)
```

I use this and the `toArray()` operator to perform set operations in the pipeline, for example to sort the observable.

```
    let sorted$ = source$.toArray().flatMap(theList=> theList.sort(this.myComparer) )
```

The output is `Observable<T>`. (**N.B** works in the context of a fixed array, not sure what would happen with a continuously generating source)

Comment: this should have been a comment to @user3743222's answer, not a new answer